# React Native Navigation Error. How do I solve this?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

In this block of code, I want to use navigation.navigate to switch between the home screen and the profile screen. But when I run the app, I get the following error: can't find variable navigation.
I've been looking for a solution, but I can't seem to find it.
Here's the code:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer, StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button title="Go to Profile Screen" onPress={()=> navigation.navigate("Profile")}/>
    </View>
  );

}
const ProfileScreen = () => {
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>Profile Screen</Text>
      <Button title="Go to Home Screen" onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")}/>
    </View>
  );

}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen 
          name="Profile" 
          component={ProfileScreen}
          options={{ title: '' }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen 
          name="Home" 
          component={HomeScreen}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `navigation` object from `props`. Code example:

```
const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button title="Go to Profile Screen" onPress={()=> navigation.navigate("Profile")}/>
    </View>
  );
}
```